# opencv putting smaller picture in larger copyTo not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to copy a smaller picture on to the larger frame. But i can't get it to work. It compiles fine but it does not show anything. My goal is to copy the recognised face onto the larger original frame.

```
//NEW
    Mat face_resized;
    //NEW
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {

        // Process face by face:
        Rect face_i = faces[i];
        // Crop the face from the image. So simple with OpenCV C++:
        Mat face = gray(face_i);

        // Resizing the face is necessary for Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces. You can easily
        // verify this, by reading through the face recognition tutorial coming with OpenCV.
        // Resizing IS NOT NEEDED for Local Binary Patterns Histograms, so preparing the
        // input data really depends on the algorithm used.
        //
        // I strongly encourage you to play around with the algorithms. See which work best
        // in your scenario, LBPH should always be a contender for robust face recognition.
        //
        // Since I am showing the Fisherfaces algorithm here, I also show how to resize the
        // face you have just found:
        //NEW
        face_resized=images[images.size()-1];
        //Mat face_resized=images[images.size()-1];
        //NEW

        cv::resize(face, face_resized, Size(im_width, im_height), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
        //model->setLabelsInfo(labelsInfo);
        // Now perform the prediction, see how easy that is:
        int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);
        double confidence = 0.0;
        model->predict(face_resized,prediction,confidence);

        // And finally write all we've found out to the original image!
        // First of all draw a green rectangle around the detected face:
        rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255,0), 1);
```

And:

```
//NEW
    cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(50,50, face_resized.cols, face_resized.rows);
    cv::Mat subview = original(roi);
    subview.copyTo(original);
    //NEW
    while(tmp!=0) {
    putText(original, tmp->name, Point(10,y),FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.0,CV_RGB(100,100,0),1.0);
    y+=10;
    tmp=tmp->next;}
    }

    imshow("face_recognizer", original);
```

(i only copied the relevant parts, can post more if needed).

Comment: Do you have a waitKey call after the imshow to give it some time to show the image?

Comment: Yes i do have that, i'll paste that as well

Answer (score 2):

`CopyTo`  method copies the matrix data to another matrix. Before copying the data, the method invokes `m.create(this->size(), this->type())` so that the destination matrix is reallocated if needed. i.e `copyto` works for same size matrices.From the your sample code,

```
cv::Mat subview = original(roi);
    subview.copyTo(original);
```

I saw that you are taking roi(`subview`) from `original` and again coping it to `original`.As `original`(big frame) is not same size that of `subview`(small) ,the original frame is reallocated in `copyTo` method to the `subview` size. To copy the small frame to big frame ,you either need to define mask and send it to `copyTO` to copy only that part(small frame) or modify the `subview` as it is part of original frame data matrix.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are saying (i'm a opencv beginner). I did get it to work when i used the greyscale Mat. How would you suggest i would get this to work instead? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you have any example code of how to do this ?

Comment: Ok how about this:    I tried this, but still doesn't work..

        cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(50,50, face_resized.cols, face_resized.rows);
 cv::Mat subview = original(roi);
 face_resized.copyTo(subview);

Compiles fine, doesn't crash, just doesn't show anything.

Comment: Yes, this code should work fine. I think now the problem may be related to some other part of the code. have you tried with saving the image to disk using imwrite,if so how does it look?

Comment: I'll try that. I'll try and add some more code as well. So if i wanted to use facerecognizer code and add the detected face to the webcam image, could i do it with the above code? As that's pretty much what i use and it's not working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be not equal pixel format of source and destination images.

e.g. Big image created as  `cv::Mat(w , h, CV_8UC3 )` and small image, having the pixel format `CV_8UC4` didn't work in my case. copyTo simply created a new image instead of writing in the ROI.